Customize subtotal text in cart page but ONLY one of them
I would like to customize the subtotal text in cart page. Unfortunately it seems that WC has the same text on both columns hardcoded (see image). I want the item subtotal text be different than the Cart Totals subtotal text. Ideally, I do not want to use modified WC templates in my child theme but use some code inside functions.php instead.
Thank you
Currently I translate both of them (using Loco)
screenshot
